# How do I make scores gained be a reflection of the dictionary in a game?

Tags: python, dictionary

I am having difficulty with the answers reflecting the dictionaries. Currently it is printing scores 1-2 instead of 15- 30, how can i amend this please?

```
import numpy as np
# This imported numpy as np

def single_game():
    
    keep_going= True
    
    ''' This is a single game of tennis, the aim of the game 
    is to score 40 points'''
    
    receiver_score = 0
    server_score = 0
    ace_winner_count = 0
    double_fault_count = 0
    service_continues_count = 0
    
    server_dict = {
        "0": 0,
        "1":15,
        "2":30,
        "3":40,
        "4": "Deuce"}
    
    
    receiver_dict = {
        "0": 0,
        "1":15,
        "2":30,
        "3":40,
        "4": "Deuce"}
    

    
    print("Hello and welcome to our Grand Slam Game!")
    print("Please roll the dice!")


    while keep_going:
       
        diceroll_yellow = np.random.randint(1, 7)

        if diceroll_yellow == 1 or diceroll_yellow == 2:
            print("The number you rolled is:", diceroll_yellow)
            print("You are the ace winner!")
            print("Points gained for server!", server_dict["1"])
            server_score += 1
            ace_winner_count += 1
            
            if server_score >= 4 or (server_score >= 4 and receiver_score <= server_score - 2):
                print("Server wins the game!")
                break
         
        elif diceroll_yellow == 3:
            print("The number you rolled is:", diceroll_yellow)
            print("Double fault")
            print("Points gained for receiver!", receiver_dict["1"])
            double_fault_count += 1
            receiver_score += 1
            if receiver_score >= 4:
                print("Receiver wins the game!")
                break
        
        else:
            print("The number you have rolled is:", diceroll_yellow)
            print("Service good")
            print("Please roll the blue dice")
            service_continues_count += 1

            diceroll_blue = np.random.randint(1, 7)

            if diceroll_blue == 1:
                print("The number you rolled is:", diceroll_blue)
                print("Receiver winner! Woop Woop!!")
                print("Points gained for receiver!", receiver_dict["1"])
                receiver_score += 1
                ace_winner_count += 1
                if receiver_score >= 4 or (receiver_score >= 4 and server_score <= receiver_score - 2):
                    print("Receiver wins the game!")
                    break
             
            elif diceroll_blue == 2:
                print("The number you rolled is:", diceroll_blue)
                print("Out! Server wins the point")
                print("Points gained for server!", server_dict["1"])
                server_score +=1
                if server_score >= 4 or (server_score >= 4 and receiver_score <= server_score - 2):
                    print("Server wins the game!")
                    break
              
            else:
                print("The number you rolled is:", diceroll_blue)
                print("Service continues")
                print("Please roll the red dice")
                service_continues_count += 1

                diceroll_red = np.random.randint(1, 7)

                if diceroll_red == 1:
                    print("The number you rolled is:", diceroll_red)
                    print("Server wins the point")
                    print("Points gained for server!", server_dict["1"])
                    server_score += 1
                    if server_score >= 4 or (server_score >= 4 and receiver_score <= server_score - 2):
                        print("Server wins the game!")
                        break
                elif diceroll_red == 2:
                    print("The number you rolled is:", diceroll_red)
                    print("Receiver wins the point")
                    receiver_score += 1
                    print("Points gained for receiver!", receiver_dict["1"])
                    if receiver_score >= 4 or (receiver_score >= 4 and server_score <= receiver_score - 2):
                        print("Receiver wins the game!")
                        break
                else:
                    print("The number you rolled is:", diceroll_red)
                    print("Service continues")
                    print("Please roll the blue dice")
                    service_continues_count += 1
                    
                    
                    if server_score >= 4 and receiver_score>=4 :
                        print("Deuce!")
                        
                        keep_going= False
                        
            #HOW TO AMEND THE SCORES LIKE IN TENNIS 

   
    print("Number of ace count:", ace_winner_count)
    print("Number of double faults:", double_fault_count)
    print("Service continues count:", service_continues_count)

    print("You have come to the end of the game!")

single_game()
```

I am expecting the printed results to be something like

15- 30

Instead of 1, 2

Comment: where do you see/get output of `1,2`?

Comment: _Instead of 1, 2_ There is no code that would produce a message of "1,2".  Please show the full exact output message, and show us the exact line of code which produces that message, and tell us what you want that message to be instead.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't played tennis n_n' so I don't understand the logic of the game, however, I've modified your code changing the way that you retrieve the values from dictionaries, you were doing this:

```
server_dict["1"]
```

but you should be doing this:

```
server_dict[str(server_score)]
```

Because you are storing and updating the scores on those variables, I recommend you to divide your code in modules. That way, it will be easier for you to set the logical process and use the debugger for checking in real time what is happening on each step of your code. You can even see which values are being stored and why is it happening:

```
import numpy as np
# This imported numpy as np

def single_game():
   
   keep_going= True
   
   ''' This is a single game of tennis, the aim of the game 
   is to score 40 points'''
   
   receiver_score = 0
   server_score = 0
   ace_winner_count = 0
   double_fault_count = 0
   service_continues_count = 0
   
   server_dict = {
      "0": 0,
      "1":15,
      "2":30,
      "3":40,
      "4": "Deuce"}
   
   
   receiver_dict = {
      "0": 0,
      "1":15,
      "2":30,
      "3":40,
      "4": "Deuce"}
      
   print("Hello and welcome to our Grand Slam Game!")
   print("Please roll the dice!")

   while keep_going:
      
      diceroll_yellow = np.random.randint(1, 7)

      print("\n")
      if diceroll_yellow == 1 or diceroll_yellow == 2:
         server_score += 1
         ace_winner_count += 1
         print("The number you rolled is:", diceroll_yellow)
         print("You are the ace winner!")
         print("Points gained for server!", server_dict[str(server_score)])
         
         
         if server_score >= 4 or (server_score >= 4 and receiver_score <= server_score - 1):
               print("Server wins the game!")
               break
      
      elif diceroll_yellow == 3:
         double_fault_count += 1
         receiver_score += 1
         print("The number you rolled is:", diceroll_yellow)
         print("Double fault")
         print("Points gained for receiver!", receiver_dict[str(receiver_score)])
         
         if receiver_score >= 4:
               print("Receiver wins the game!")
               break
      
      else:
         print("The number you have rolled is:", diceroll_yellow)
         print("Service good")
         print("Please roll the blue dice")
         service_continues_count += 1

         diceroll_blue = np.random.randint(1, 7)

         if diceroll_blue == 1:
               receiver_score += 1
               ace_winner_count += 1
               print("The number you rolled is:", diceroll_blue)
               print("Receiver winner! Woop Woop!!")
               print("Points gained for receiver!", receiver_dict[str(receiver_score)])
               
               if receiver_score >= 4 or (receiver_score >= 4 and server_score <= receiver_score - 2):
                  print("Receiver wins the game!")
                  break
            
         elif diceroll_blue == 2:
               server_score +=1
               print("The number you rolled is:", diceroll_blue)
               print("Out! Server wins the point")
               print("Points gained for server!", server_dict[str(server_score)])
               
               if server_score >= 4 or (server_score >= 4 and receiver_score <= server_score - 2):
                  print("Server wins the game!")
                  break
            
         else:
               print("The number you rolled is:", diceroll_blue)
               print("Service continues")
               print("Please roll the red dice")
               service_continues_count += 1

               diceroll_red = np.random.randint(1, 7)

               if diceroll_red == 1:
                  server_score += 1
                  print("The number you rolled is:", diceroll_red)
                  print("Server wins the point")
                  print("Points gained for server!", server_dict[str(server_score)])
                  
                  if server_score >= 4 or (server_score >= 4 and receiver_score <= server_score - 2):
                     print("Server wins the game!")
                     break
               elif diceroll_red == 2:
                  print("The number you rolled is:", diceroll_red)
                  print("Receiver wins the point")
                  receiver_score += 1
                  print("Points gained for receiver!", receiver_dict[str(receiver_score)])
                  if receiver_score >= 4 or (receiver_score >= 4 and server_score <= receiver_score - 2):
                     print("Receiver wins the game!")
                     break
               else:
                  print("The number you rolled is:", diceroll_red)
                  print("Service continues")
                  print("Please roll the blue dice")
                  service_continues_count += 1
                  
                  
                  if server_score >= 4 and receiver_score>=4 :
                     print("Deuce!")
                     
                     keep_going= False
                     
         #HOW TO AMEND THE SCORES LIKE IN TENNIS 


   print("Number of ace count:", ace_winner_count)
   print("Number of double faults:", double_fault_count)
   print("Service continues count:", service_continues_count)

   print("You have come to the end of the game!")

single_game()
```